# Facebook like button - on an ebay page?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook

I need to get someone a facebook like button. Now, this would usually be very easy (with facebook's hackjob of an API with iframes), but, he/she wants it on an Ebay page. How would I go about this? Ebay doesn't seem to allow Javascript on seller pages, so, maybe a static like button, that a php script updates (somehow)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

eBay doesn't allow iframes or javacsript.

That is why this company called 3DSellers came with ShareYourItems app which is inserting Share & Like buttons with Flash (which is allowed):
http://www.3dsellers.com/products/share-your-items/

Comment: AWESOME! I'll write it in Flash, you're great.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the ebay infrastructure too well, but maybe you can use open graph api.
For your reference:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/opengraph/

Comment: Adding a like button pretty much ends up adding JS.

Comment: Well, the last option would be to create a like button of your own and use ajax to run the code to "Like" something. I have been trying to do that for a few months now, on and off. I need it in order to add a "Wall" to an iframe app. This is where I got the idea: http://www.facebook.com/#!/AKON?sk=app_178091127385. If you ever get this going, I`d love to know :)

Answer (score 1):

here is the place for the Facebook generator http://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/

ok your code in Dream weaver when you start out looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN"           "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>
</html>
```

ok when you add the first part of the HTML5  generated code from facebook your code should look similar to this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
</body>
</html>
```

ok then the second part of the code gets inserted and it should look something  like this except with your info:

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
</head>

<body>
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script>(function(d, s, id) {
  var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
  if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
  js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
  js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js#xfbml=1";
  fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
}(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));</script>
</body>
</html>
<div class="fb-send" data-href="http://example.com"></div>
```

Copy the whole code from dreamweaver into the top of an ebay listing under the html tab.

Comment: Dreamweaver, what a blast from the past.

Comment: you can check out my listings and almost all of them have an auto-play  flash movie and a "like" button in them. there are links on my web page: www.mojotrading.biz to my ebay listings and store to show that it can be done.

Comment: Auto-play flash movie? I'll make sure not to visit them.

Comment: i dont add sound to them because ebay frowns on that. but they are lightweight only about 300k

Answer (score 0):

does Ebay allow iframes?
Then you could implement the iframe-variant of the like button.

Look here and copy the plain iframe-tag from the generated sourcecode:
http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/plugins/like/

Answer (score 0):

Ok I have accomplished this in Dreamweaver cs 6.

- open DW
- create new html
- in the code mode go to the tag in the code that says < body>
- after < body> copy from facebook html generator the first portion of the HTML 5 code
- paste it after the < body> in DW
- copy the second part of the facebook HTML 5 code and paste in DW after the < /body>
  copy the whole code in DW and put in the HTML portion of listing on ebay at the Top of the listing and put two dots after the code to mark it for easy referance

submit listing in ebay

I even added a swf flash movie to my code and works fine. I have a Facebook like button on my store page and on my listings, as well as an auto play flash slideshow of my items. all free no third party app. 
P.S. all pictures or flash movies have to be on a Third party host site for them to work.
you can check out my website at [www.mojotrading.biz](http://www.mojotrading.biz/) there will be links there to direct you to my ebay pages to show you what it looks like.

Comment: Joe, you have to make an effort to present a clear answer, I can't even edit your answer to correct it because I cannot make sense of half you are trying to say.

Comment: Yes, I can't say if it is a correct answer but at least now people will understand it and rate it.